# Thymeleaf display field of object of a list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have

```
<table style="padding-top: 15px; padding-left: 50px; width: 1366px;">
    <tr>
        <thead>
        <th>STT</th>
        <th width="24%">Số tài khoản</th>
        <th width="24%">Tên ngân hàng</th>
        <th width="24%">Chi nhánh</th>
        <th width="24%">Tỉnh/TP của ngân hàng</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="item, itemStat : ${accountObjectForm.accountObjectBankAccountList}">
            <td><span th:text="${itemStat.index + 1}"></span></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:value="${accountObjectForm.accountObjectBankAccountList[0].bankAccount}" th:name="|accountObjectBankAccountList[${itemStat.index}].bankAccount|" th:id="|accountObjectBankAccountList[${itemStat.index}].bankAccount|" class="k-textbox" style="width: 100%;"></td>
            <td><input type="number" th:name="|accountObjectBankAccountList[${itemStat.index}].bankId|" th:id="|accountObjectBankAccountList[${itemStat.index}].bankId|" class="k-textbox" style="width: 100%"></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:name="|accountObjectBankAccountList[${itemStat.index}].bankBranchName|" th:id="|accountObjectBankAccountList[${itemStat.index}].bankBranchName|" class="k-textbox" style="width: 100%;"></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:name="|accountObjectBankAccountList[${itemStat.index}].province|" th:id="|accountObjectBankAccountList[${itemStat.index}].province|" class="k-textbox" style="width: 100%;"></td>
        </tr>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var dataBank = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "/banks_json",
                            dataType: "json"
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 30
                });

                $("input[name$='bankId']").each(function() {
                    $(this).kendoDropDownList({
                        optionLabel: "Chọn...",
                        dataTextField: "bankCode",
                        dataValueField: "id",
                        dataSource: dataBank,
                        index: 0,
                        change: onChangeBank
                    })
                });

                var dataProvinceBank = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "/provinces",
                            dataType: "json"
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 300
                });

                $("input[name$='province']").each(function() {
                    $(this).kendoDropDownList({
                        optionLabel: "Chọn...",
                        dataTextField: "text",
                        dataValueField: "value",
                        filter: "contains",
                        dataSource: dataProvinceBank,
                        index: 0,
                        change: onChangeProvinceBank
                    })
                });
            });
            function onChangeBank() { }
            function onChangeProvinceBank() { }
        </script>
        </tbody>
    </tr>
</table>
```

result
[image]

(Open image in new tab for see bigger screenshot)

Under the hood
[image]

I try

```
<td><input type="text" th:value="${accountObjectForm.accountObjectBankAccountList[${itemStat.index}].bankAccount}" th:name="|accountObjectBankAccountList[${itemStat.index}].bankAccount|" th:id="|accountObjectBankAccountList[${itemStat.index}].bankAccount|" class="k-textbox" style="width: 100%;"></td>
```

but error, the page cannot render to html when catch these line of code.

I use `0` for a holder. Please help me change the number `0` by index of list.

```
th:value="${accountObjectForm.accountObjectBankAccountList[0].bankAccount}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit inner `${...}` braces in your expressions, refer to `itemStat.index` directly. You are already using thymeleaf expression syntax, no need to use it twice.

Not sure if this is the only problem with your code, but surely first to fix

Answer (score 1):

An another solution

```
<td><input type="text" th:value="${accountObjectForm.accountObjectBankAccountList[__${itemStat.index}__].bankAccount}" th:name="|accountObjectBankAccountList[${itemStat.index}].bankAccount|" th:id="|accountObjectBankAccountList[${itemStat.index}].bankAccount|" class="k-textbox" style="width: 100%;"></td>
```